# List days occuring in dataset

Tags: mongodb

I have this huge dataset for which every entry has a datetime field. The data was inserted irregularly. For example:

```
2015-04-20 : 500 entries,
2015-04-23 : 300 entries,
2015-05-01 : 600 entries
```

The thing is, I do not know when these active days are. What I would like is a mongodb query which returns some sort of array containing all days which occur in the database, like so:

```
['2015-04-20,
'2015-04-23,
'2015-04-23,
'2015-04-25,
'2015-05-01,
'2015-05-05,
'2015-05-09]
```

Is this possible, and if so: how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the data type of your datetime field a string or a Date?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "distinct" command that has shell wrapper, which can be used something like:

```
db.collection.distinct(dateFieldName, query)
```

If you are not running it from shell, check whether your driver wraps this command, if not you can use the command directly:

```
{ distinct: "<collection>", key: "<field>", query: <query> }
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/#dbcmd.distinct

If your time stamp field needs some additinal processing, you can use aggregation framework.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: $substr: ["$timestamp", 0, 10]}}]
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/core/aggregation-introduction/

Comment: I was looking at that right now, but the problem is that the datetime field is something like `2015-04-29T09:54:36Z`, so running a distinct on that just shows all unique datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a field named `dateField` that contains `Date` values, you can use the aggregation [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) with `$group` to do this.

It's easiest if you're using Mongo 3.x where the [`$dateToString`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#exp._S_dateToString) operator is available:

```javascript
db.dates.aggregate([
   {$group: {
       _id: {$dateToString: {format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$dateField'}},
       count: {$sum: 1}
   }},
   {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
```

Prior to 3.0 you need to use multiple date operators to piece together the date into the `_id` when grouping:

```javascript
db.dates.aggregate([
   {$group: {
       _id: {
           year: {$year: '$dateField'}, 
           month: {$month: '$dateField'}, 
           day: {$dayOfMonth: '$dateField'}
       },
       count: {$sum: 1}
   }},
   {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
```

In both cases, note the use of `$sort` to order the results by the number of docs on each day, descending.